# Nesting connected redux containers and presentational components in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, containers

I have read similar questions before but none seem to fix my issue what I'm trying to accomplish. I must be blind or misunderstanding something fundamentally.

- [Nesting a container component in a presentational component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845866/nesting-a-container-component-in-a-presentational-component) (Stackoverflow)
- [Why using nested connect react redux components is good](https://hackernoon.com/why-using-nested-connect-react-redux-components-is-good-bd17997b53d2) (Medium)

My code example is the following:

[image: Edit 43w8vkl554]

When I'm nesting components I get the following structure:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    { /* container component connected via redux (has as you can see props.children) */ }
    <Navigation>
        { /* presentational component */ }
        <Main>
            { /* container component connected via redux */ }
            <Counter />
        </Main>
    </Navigation>
</Provider>
```

While this seems rather intuitive I am receiving weird errors I can't explain (would be nice if someone can). In the browser the error is:

`You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received undefined` (Navigation.tsx) I'm not even sure if the error is related to nesting components. When i change counter to be the presentational component everything works as expected. Typescript or my implementation has issues with containers inside already connected components.

In the sandbox the error seems to come from composing `counter` inside `main`. Am I missing something? A type maybe?

I understand that I can solve this issue by nesting only inside my top-level `navigation` container mapping/connecting only once with the store but this is not the solution I'm looking for. I would rather want to take the advise of https://stackoverflow.com/a/38537606/222474.

Thanks in advance for the help.

**Edit:**

While @Tomasz has solved the error, I don't understand why this is happening. Skimming through https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html didn't help either. Is this somewhat type related for `index.js` exports? If someone can add clarification, this could be helpful.

**Answer:**

This is due to circular references where some components are imported before others, hence beeing `undefined`. This is quite common and it happened to me many time. The solution is just like the accepted answer: import your component directly.

Comment: `console.log("Counter", CounterComponent);` logs `"Counter, undefined"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't explain what the actual error is, but there is some problem with the imports from *components/index.tsx*.

Correcting *container/Counter.tsx* to:

```
import CounterComponent from "../components/Counter";
```

and *container/Navigation.tsx*

```
import NavigationComponent from "../components/Navigation";
```

the error that `connect` produces will disappear.

Interestingly if you change the following in *container/Counter.tsx*

```
import * as all from '../components';
console.log(all)
```

Previously your code will log an empty object. Once I changed the imports to the way above - it logs the entire object with the components as entries.

Comment: Wow. It indeed works (+1 minor bug in code). Is this normal? I'm used to export through `index.js` all the time. Now i need to specify the actual module i'm interested in? Why does this work in `constants` then?

Comment: @proxylittle It actually works... change the imports to above and then if you do `import * as all from '../components';` the `all` will be a full Object. Not sure why is this though...

Comment: Yes i have tested, your code fully works (I found a different bug in my code somewhere else; default state = {} was missing). This is the weirdest bug/error i have ever seen and i can't understand it. Reading https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html didn't give me a clue either so far. I'll mark it as solved though.